# Can I replicate a standby VM between two exsi hosts in VMware vSphere Essentials Plus Kit without a cluster

Tags: backup, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere

I will get getting two physical hosts with their own internal storage (not shared or in a HA cluster) and VMware vSphere Essentials Plus Kit.   There is a requirement to have a 'near up to date' copy of one of the VMs stored on the 1st host copied frequently to the 2nd host.

In VMware vSphere Essentials Plus Kit you get vsphere replicater, but from what I can tell this is to replicate VMs between different vSpheres, not different hosts.  Is this correct?

From searching, I have seen people mention to buy veeam replicator, but I would like to know if this is possible without purchasing more software.

Many thanks if you can help shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vSphere replication to replicate from one host to another. It is not only for cross-vSphere migrations.

Veeam's Backup suite can do the same thing with a lot less complexity. So while the built-in vSphere replication product works, recovering from it is a bit of a pain. Veeam is very inexpensive for two hosts, so it's probably worth the additional cost.

Both software solutions allow you to go down to 15-minute replication intervals.